# Stop reloading UItableView again and again in Iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am working on a chat app,In that i have used `UITableView` for chatting screen. In every chat bubble user's profile pic is there,Now my issue is when a new message come or i am sending new message whole `tableView` is reloading with images in chat bubble also, I want to stop it,Can anybody help me to figure it out?
**my code is:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == self.chatTableView)
    {
        NSString *cellID;
        if([[((UUMessageFrame *)(self.chatModel.dataSource[indexPath.row])) message] from] == UUMessageFromMe)
        {
            cellID = @"outgoing_cell";
        }
        else
        {
            cellID = @"incoming_cell";
        }
        //commented by jigar
       // UUMessageCell *cell =  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
      //   UUMessageCell *cell = [tableView];

        UUMessageCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UUMessageCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
            cell.delegate = self;
            if ([cellID isEqualToString:@"outgoing_cell"])
            {
                //                cell.recognizer.numberOfTapsRequired
                [cell.recognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
            }
        }
        [cell setMessageFrame:self.chatModel.dataSource[indexPath.row]];
        NSLog(@" text message is  : %@",[cell.btnContent titleForState:UIControlStateNormal]);
        cell.btnContent.tag = indexPath.row;
        return cell;
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *cellIdentifier;/* = isOutgoingMessage ? self.outgoingCellIdentifier : self.incomingCellIdentifier;*/
        if ([[self.arrTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isKindOfClass:[OTRVoice class]])
        {
            OTRVoice *voice = (OTRVoice *)[self.arrTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            if(![voice.fk_Tripper isEqualToString:appDelegate.account.uniqueId])
            {
                cellIdentifier = self.incomingCellIdentifier;
            }
            else
            {
                cellIdentifier = self.outgoingCellIdentifier;
            }
        }
        else{
            cellIdentifier = self.outgoingCellIdentifier;
        }
        @try
        {
            VoiceTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.avatarImage.clipsToBounds = YES;
            cell.avatarImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.avatarImage.bounds.size.width / 2.0;
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            tableview.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
            cell.circular_ProgressView.frame = CGRectMake(cell.btnPlay.frame.origin.x-2, cell.btnPlay.frame.origin.y, 26, 26);
            [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.tag = indexPath.row +10000;
            return cell;
        }
        @catch(NSException *e)
        {
            NSLog(@"Exception is : %@",e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For load image you can use SDWebImage library.

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage library. 
In this lib you can set the image directly to `UIImageview` using lazy loading concept. So even if you set image every time. it will not download again and again.

check the below code for example.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"url"];

[cell.avatarImage setImageWithURL:url usingActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
```

Comment: I have used the same,Still when i scroll up and down image is always reload.:( can u pls help me what is wrong with my code,as it has taken my 3 days..:(

Comment: I did not find anywhere that you have used SDWebImage.